# Send existing geolocation data from cloud server to Live Objects

Tags: rest, api, cloud, orange-api

I currently have a running instance in Google Cloud which stores geolocation data from an IoT device. I wanted to connect my Google Cloud server to Live Objects so that these geolocation data can be used. Is there a way to connect Google Cloud and Live Objects together, to share data? Or is there a way to send a post request from an external server script (Node.js) to Live Objects without using MQTT? The post request is just a normal HTTP post. The HTTP post will be sent using REST API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can push data in Live Objects by using HTTPS REST API

check https://liveobjects.orange-business.com/swagger-ui/index.html#!/Data_management_data_store/addDataMessageUsingPOST

and example here: https://liveobjects.orange-business.com/doc/html/lo_manual.html#STREAMS

cheers